# create relationship based on two columns

Tags: relationship, powerpivot, powerbi

I have two tables like below

```
Table 01

Company          Date                Size

A                01/05/2000          30

A                01/06/2000          40

B                01/05/2000          80

B                01/06/2000          90
```

```
Table 02

Company          Date               sales

A                01/05/2000          30

A                01/06/2000          40

B                01/05/2000          80

B                 01/06/2000          90
```

I want to create relationship between these two tables based on date and company.
How to create relationship between two tables?

Thanks in advance

Comment: ...What do you expect it to be? The two tables look like duplicates. What do you mean by "create a relationship"?

Comment: The first table has size column,the second has sales column. I want to bring sales column to table one. I thought it can be done after making relationships between two tables, by using related() function.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you so much. I am trying to do this on powerpivot data model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Power Pivot / Data Model, you can only use one column in a relationship.  You can concatenate columns in a new calculated column using the **&** operator, e.g.

`= 'Table 01'[Company] & "|" & 'Table 01'[Date]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Table 1 is column A, B, C in "Sheet1", and Table 2 the same, but in "Sheet2", you can just use a `Index/Match` (entered with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>.

In your Table 1, go to D2 (the first non-header row in column D, next to the `30`), and use this formula:

`=Index(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$10,Match($A2&$B2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$10&Sheet2!$B$2:$B$10,0))`

I'm assuming your last row is `10`, if not, just change that in all parts of the formula.  This should leave you with:

```
Table 01

Company          Date                Size

A                01/05/2000          30                30

A                01/06/2000          40                40

B                01/05/2000          80                80

B                01/06/2000          90                90
```